# DacServices Rollback if new constraint validation fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, dac

We are updating our databases using the `DacServices`. However sometimes new constraints get added that cause Constraint Violations, which require us to write a migration script to make sure the Data in the column is valid.

However with the `DacServices.Deploy` if the `ScriptNewConstraintValidation` option is true and the new constraint errors, I cannot figure out how to rollback the changes made by the DacServices.

We are using the AlwaysOn Availability so performing a backup/restore would be extremely difficult. Below is one way I have tried with no success.

```
var dacServices = new DacServices(dbConnection.ConnectionString);
var deploymentOptions = new DacDeployOptions
{
    CreateNewDatabase = createNewDatabase,
    ScriptDatabaseCompatibility = false,
    ScriptDatabaseCollation = false,
    IgnoreUserSettingsObjects = true,
    DropPermissionsNotInSource = false,
    DropRoleMembersNotInSource = false,
    IgnorePermissions = true,
    IgnoreRoleMembership = true,
    GenerateSmartDefaults = true,
    IncludeTransactionalScripts = true,
    ScriptNewConstraintValidation = true
};

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage dacPackage = DacPackage.Load(dacPath);

Console.WriteLine("Deploying DacPac");
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    dacServices.Deploy(dacPackage, databaseName, true, deploymentOptions, tokenSource.Token);
}
catch(Exception)
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `IncludeTransactionalScripts` take care of this for you? Doesn't that force the deployment to be an all-or-nothing operation?

Comment: That was what I had thought, But when I looked at the database after the Deploy I saw the new constraint was created as CHECK which meant that the next Deploy said it was successful.

Comment: So you're saying that the deployment goes through even though the constraint validation fails?

Comment: Correct. It will throw an exception stopping the rest of the TeamCity BuildSteps. But if you just run it a second time it will complete fully because that constraint already exists so it doesn't validate it again.

Comment: Do you think that you are cancelling the rollback step with your `CancellationToken`?

Comment: No, I had the same result before trying to add the CancellationToken. It almost seems like the ScriptNewConstraintValidation is run after the transaction is completed.

Comment: That is frustrating. I developed an app that uses schema compare too. We generate a script, modify it and then execute it by way of SQLCMD. One of the ways that we modify the script is by wrapping the entire thing in a transaction. We insert `BEGIN TRANSACTION` right after `USE [$(DatabaseName)]; GO` and then `COMMIT TRANSACTION` at the very end of the file. A bit hacky, I know, but perhaps that is a workaround?

Comment: I was worried that would be the only option. I just implemented this and it is working perfectly. If you want to post this as an answer I'll approve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here, as the OP points out, is that the step to validate the new constraints happens *outside* of the transactional statements that are included when `IncludeTransactionalScripts` is set to `true`. This means that the changes to the database will be committed, even though the deployment specifies constraints that are inconsistent with the data in the database. This seems like a bug that Microsoft should fix.

Nonetheless, my suggestion was to use the `DacServices` framework to generate a deployment *script*, as opposed to just deploying directly to the database. Once the script has been generated, you can add transactional statements to ensure that the *entirety* of the script executes as an atomic transaction. You would insert a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement right after the `USE [$(DatabaseName)]; GO` statement and then a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` statement at the very end of the script.

Two things to note, though: 1) the generated script *must* be executed from `SQLCMD` (you can't just execute it using a C# `SqlConnection` or even an SMO `ServerConnection` for instance), 2) I would suggest that if you manually wrap the script in a transaction, you skip the step of setting `IncludeTransactionalScripts` to `true`.